# Debian: installing a python package: apt-get or apt-src?

Tags: debian, package-management, python

I tried to install a `mutagen` package, available according to `apt-cache`:

```
$ apt-cache madison mutagen
   mutagen |   1.40.0-2 | http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
```

`apt-get` won't deliver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mutagen
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mutagen
```

I tried `apt-src`:

```
$ sudo apt-src install mutagen
```

The result was catastrophic: it made a grand show, apparently installing the entire python and everything (already present in the system).

So I have to (a) locate the damage and remove it and (b) install mutagen the right way. How am I supposed to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mutagen |   1.40.0-2 | http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
> ```

says that `mutagen` is a source package, not a binary package. If you want to install the Python module using `apt-get`, you need to find the relevant binary package;

```
apt showsrc mutagen
```

will list them. You presumably want either

```
sudo apt install python3-mutagen
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-mutagen
```

depending on the version of Python you’re installing.

Cleaning up after your `sudo apt-src install` will involve removing any build-dependency you don’t need. Look at the `Build-Depends` line in the output from `apt showsrc` above, and remove any package you don’t think you need — one good approach is to mark them as automatically installed, then autoremove:

```
sudo apt-mark auto debhelper dh-python faad flac libc-bin oggz-tools pypy pypy-hypothesis pypy-pytest python-all python-docutils python-hypothesis python-pycodestyle python-pyflakes python-pytest python2.7-doc python3-all python3-hypothesis python3-pycodestyle python3-pyflakes python3-pytest python3-sphinx python3-sphinx-rtd-theme python3.7-doc vorbis-tools
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks! `apt showsrc mutagen/apt install python3-mutagen` works just right. Only `vorbis-tools` got autoremoved from my longish `Build-Depends` list. All the other packages are either `Unable to locate` or `not found by glob/regex` Does it look right?

Comment: That looks OK; I’d have to know exactly what `apt-src install` did on your system to say conclusively. Since `apt install` works, at least your packages are consistent which means your system isn’t broken ;-).

Comment: The system does not appear to be broken, indeed. Let's consider he problem to be solved. Thank you very much!